# functions.database.ref & Auto ID

Tags: firebase, admin, ref

able to get function.database.ref to work for basic chains like this.

```
functions.database.ref("/following/{uid}/{followingId}").onCreate(event => { 
  var uid = event.params.uid; 
  var fromId = event.params.fromId
```

however I have no idea what to do when we are creating something with an autoId that has a sub branch in this case fromId.

```
 exports.NewActMessage = functions.database.ref("/ActPosts/{uid}/messages/autoId/{fromId}").onCreate(event => {

   var uid = event.params.uid; //JOSIAH SAVINO
   var fromId = event.params.fromId
```

Whats even more challenging is the autoId is what is being created but I need to pull the "fromId" information from the branch inside of the autoId.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9rmZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase messaged me how to get first the autoId than the fromId from that like so...

```
exports.NewActMessage = 
functions.database.ref('/ActPosts/{uid}/messages/{autoId}').onCreate(event => {
var uid = event.params.uid; 
var autoId = event.params.autoId; 
var fromId = event.data.val().fromId;
```